# Can't download entire file using urllib2

Tags: python, excel, urllib2

Hi I'm trying to download an excel file from this url (http://www.sicom.gov.co/precios/controller?accion=ExportToExcel) and then I need to parse it using xlrd.

The problem is that when I put that Url on a browser I get an excel file of more or less 2MB, but when I download the file using urllib2, http2lib or even curl from command line I only get a 4k file and obviously parsing that incomplete file fails miserably.

Strangely enough xlrd seems to be able to read the correct sheet name from the downloaded file so I'm guessing the file is the right one but it is clearly incomplete.

Here is some sample code of what I'm trying to achieve

```
import urllib2
from xlrd import open_workbook

excel_url = 'http://www.sicom.gov.co/precios/controller?accion=ExportToExcel'

result = urllib2.urlopen(excel_url)
wb = open_workbook(file_contents=result.read())
response = ""
for s in wb.sheets():
            response += 'Sheet:' + s.name + '<br>'
            for row in range(s.nrows):
                values = []
                for col in range(s.ncols):
                    value = s.cell(row, col).value
                    if (value):
                        values.append(str(value) + " not empty")
                    else:
                        values.append("Value at " + col + ", " + row + " was empty")
                response += str(values) + "<br>"
```

Comment: If I paste that link into my browser I only get a file named `controller` that is 4.1KB.

Comment: @jucas You probably have a session at this server which sends you a different file than us.

Comment: You probably have to sign into the website to access that file right? That is why you can't get it from your script.

Comment: @jramirez thanks! actually I don't have to login, it is a public website (http://www.sicom.gov.co/precios/controller?accion=Home&option=SEARCH_PRECE) from there I just click on the excel Icon and copy the link I get from the window that opens up. Funnily when I try the url on my regular Chrome window I get the 2MB excel file, but when I open a new Incognito window and paste the exact same URL I get the 4K file. I guess there is some hidden parameter/cookie that gets passed when I access the link from my regular chrome window, that doesn't work from Incognito mode or from my script

Comment: @LutzHorn I think you are right! how could a simulate a similar session from my script, or at least how could I see what session parameters I'm using?

Comment: @jucas el que dice `exportar a Excel` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call your first url first. It seems to set a cookie or something like that. Then call the second one to download the excel file. For that kind of jobs, you should prefer http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/#, because it's much easier to use than the standard lib tools and it handles special cases (like cookies) much better by default.

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.get('http://www.sicom.gov.co/precios/controller?accion=Home&option=SEARCH_PRECE')
response = s.get('http://www.sicom.gov.co/precios/controller?accion=ExportToExcel')

with file('out.xls','wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```